# Angular2: HammerJS swipe for md-tab-group

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, hammer.js

I've implemented **HammerJS** in my **Angular2** webapp and I've also tested the [example](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-hammerjs-touch-gesture-in-angular-2#the-app-component) code out. This code uses an Array of objects and seems to work flawlessly. However, I've been trying to implement the same system for @angular2-material/tabs. Therefore I have a `<md-tab-group>` with multiple `<md-tab>`'s which should swipe from tab to tab. Problem is that I can't even trigger the swipe function.

*HTML-File*:

```
<md-tab-group md-stretch-tabs [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex" (selectedIndexChange)="selectChange()">
      <div class="swipe-box" (swipeleft)="swipe(idx, $event.type)" (swiperight)="swipe(idx, $event.type)">
        <md-tab>
           (...) //Content Tab 1
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab>
           (...) //Content Tab 2
        </md-tab>
      </div>
</md-tab-group>
```

In the example can be seen that `*ngFor` is used like `*ngFor="let avatar of avatars; let idx=index"` for the  swipe-box-`<div>`. But since I'm getting my index from the `<md-tab-group>` it doesn't seem neccesary and even when I include it, my event isn't triggered but my `<md-tab>`-content becomes hidden. Therefore I left it out. I did leave the `idx` parameter in the function because the swipe method expects a number (second parameter is optional). [Documentation](https://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-swipe/)

For the TypeScript-file I've implemented the following code (some code might not work but haven't been able to test it since the swipe method doesn't get called).

*TS-File*:

```
export class HomeComponent {

  selectedIndex: number = 1;

  selectChange(): void{
    console.log("event triggered INDEX: " + this.selectedIndex);
  }

  SWIPE_ACTION = { LEFT: 'swipeleft', RIGHT: 'swiperight' };

  // Action triggered when user swipes
  swipe(selectedIndex: number, action = this.SWIPE_ACTION.RIGHT) {
    console.log("swiped"); //DOES NOT GET TRIGGERD
    // Out of range
    if (selectedIndex < 0 || selectedIndex > 1 ) return;

    let nextIndex = 0;
    // Swipe right, next tab
    if (action === this.SWIPE_ACTION.RIGHT) {
      const isLast = selectedIndex === 1;
      nextIndex = isLast ? 0 : selectedIndex + 1;
      console.log("swipe right");
    }

    // Swipe left, previous tab
    if (action === this.SWIPE_ACTION.LEFT) {
      const isFirst = selectedIndex === 0;
      nextIndex = isFirst ? 1 : selectedIndex - 1;
      console.log("swipe left");
    }
  }
}
```

*[Live demo of what HammerJS does](https://plnkr.co/edit/LCsiXOtzSedGZDbGQ3f8?p=preview)* **and yes**, I've implemented the script needed in the index.html

```
<!-- Hammer JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem appeared to be that the swipe-event is used in the wrong `<div>`. The event needs to be triggered in the **parent** `<div>`. here's the working code:

*HTML-File*:

```
<div class="md-content" flex md-scroll-y (swipeleft)="swipe(idx, $event.type)" (swiperight)="swipe(idx, $event.type)">
   <md-tab-group md-stretch-tabs [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex" (selectedIndexChange)="selectChange()">
           <md-tab>
              (...) //Content Tab 1
           </md-tab>
           <md-tab>
              (...) //Content Tab 2
           </md-tab>
   </md-tab-group>
</div
```

*TS-File*:

```
export class HomeComponent {

  selectedIndex: number = 1;

  selectChange(): void{
    console.log("Selected INDEX: " + this.selectedIndex);
  }

  SWIPE_ACTION = { LEFT: 'swipeleft', RIGHT: 'swiperight' };

  // Action triggered when user swipes
  swipe(selectedIndex: number, action = this.SWIPE_ACTION.RIGHT) {
    // Out of range
    if (this.selectedIndex < 0 || this.selectedIndex > 1 ) return;

    // Swipe left, next tab
    if (action === this.SWIPE_ACTION.LEFT) {
      const isLast = this.selectedIndex === 1;
      this.selectedIndex = isLast ? 0 : this.selectedIndex + 1;
      console.log("Swipe right - INDEX: " + this.selectedIndex);
    }

    // Swipe right, previous tab
    if (action === this.SWIPE_ACTION.RIGHT) {
      const isFirst = this.selectedIndex === 0;
      this.selectedIndex = isFirst ? 1 : this.selectedIndex - 1;
      console.log("Swipe left - INDEX: " + this.selectedIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a small directive to accomplish the same effect then your code:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[swipeTab]'
})
export class SwipeTabDirective {

  @HostListener('swipeleft', ['$event'])
  onSwipeleft(event) {
    if(this.selectedIndex + 1 <= this.tabs - 1) {
      this.selectedIndex += 1;
      this.selectedIndexChange.emit(this.selectedIndex);
    }
  }

  @HostListener('swiperight', ['$event'])
  onSwiperight(event) {
    if(this.selectedIndex - 1 >= 0) {
      this.selectedIndex -= 1;
      this.selectedIndexChange.emit(this.selectedIndex);
    }
  }

  @Input() tabs: number;
  @Input()  selectedIndex: number;
  @Output() selectedIndexChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

}
```

The template should look like this:

```
<md-tab-group md-stretch-tabs [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex" [(tabs)]="tabs" swipeTab>
       <md-tab>
          (...) //Content Tab 2
       </md-tab>
       <md-tab>
          (...) //Content Tab 2
       </md-tab>
       <md-tab>
          (...) //Content Tab 3
       </md-tab>           
</md-tab-group>
```

And in the component you have to declare the following variables:

```
  selectedIndex: number = 0;
  tabs: number = 3;
```

Have fun with it.

Comment: No, you still require HammerJS, because the swipeleft and swiperight event comes from HammerJS.

Comment: hey @MaxPayne, html is saying Can't bind to 'tabs' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("ction> though I have declared tabs in component file.

Comment: 0. it worked for me :)!
1. make sure to import hammerjs so that directive may work properly: https://medium.com/the-dev-newbie/integrating-hammerjs-with-angular-7fab8186510c
2. remember to import SwipeTabDirective in correct module!

Answer (score 3):

You need the swipe detection on each tab, not the container.

```
  <div class="swipe-box">
    <md-tab (swipeleft)="swipe(1, $event.type)" 
            (swiperight)="swipe(1, $event.type)">
       (...) //Content Tab 1
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab (swipeleft)="swipe(2, $event.type)" 
            (swiperight)="swipe(2, $event.type)">
       (...) //Content Tab 2
    </md-tab>
  </div>
```

Comment: Scratch that,  the example has it on the `<div>` too so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Yes but the DIV is replicated using *ngFor so the swipe handlers end up  on each avatar div. Inspect the running code.  Your solution above works too because the tab group keeps selected index.  Fun stuff. Glad you solved it:)

Comment: Thank you for elaborating this. Like I said before, it did make sense that it could have been an issue and your explenation perfectly explained why it did, thanks!